# Designing a piston pump for windpump

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-engineering, fluid-mechanics, design, renewable-energy

I am designing a savonius type wind pump for low wind speeds(avg speed = 2.7 m/s), with these speeds and rotor area of about 2 m<sup>2</sup>. Acc. to my calculations, I am getting a volume flow rate of 50 ml/s at 10 m lift head, for this flow rate, is it feasible to build a piston pump of diameter 1.5 inch and stroke of about 4 cm. Is there a minimum limit on stroke length of a piston pump which is feasible?

Comment: They are plentiful see: http://www.ironmanwindmill.com/

Comment: The standard manual well pumps such as Monitors (by Baker Mfg) can be set up like that. 4cm is a bit short, I'd go with a size smaller bore and a bit more stroke if you can find a smaller cylinder. The three pivot positions on a Monitor force pump handle yield 10", 7.5", and 5" strokes at max articulation. (I used to work with these for the USFS). I'd go back and rejigger things around a 1 11/16 dia and 5" stroke. You'll wear stuff out too fast with a really short stroke. [monitor](https://www.deanbennettsupply.com/brass-well-cylinders.html)